# Need to toggle bg-dark in bootstrap collapse targeted card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just want to customize bootstrap 4 collapse and I almost succeeded but there is an issue with the jquery. I want that whenever someone click on any card's header, Then it's background color should be dark with white text but in my case it is not working instead of that all card heading's background color are changing. Following is the code example:

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.card-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  
        $(".card-heading").toggleClass('bg-dark');
  $(".card-heading").toggleClass('text-light');
}
$('.card-groups').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.card-groups').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
    .card-groups .card {
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .card-groups .card-default {
        border-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .card-groups .card-default > .card-heading {
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #212121;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .card-groups .card-title {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .card-groups h4.card-title {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .card-groups .card-title > a {
        color: #454545;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .card-groups .more-less {
        float: right;
        color: #454545;
      font-size:20px;
    }

    .card-groups .card-default > .card-heading + .panel-collapse > .card-body {
        border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
    background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container demo">
    
    <div class="card-groups" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne"> 
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="card-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- panel-group -->
    
    
</div><!-- container -->
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to add to the style sheet, just toggle at the right places

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {

  let myhead = $(e.target)
    .prev('.card-heading');
  myhead
    .find(".more-less")
    .toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus text-light');

  myhead.toggleClass('bg-dark').find('.card-title')
    .find('a').toggleClass('text-white');

}
$('.card-groups').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
.card-groups .card {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-groups .card-default {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.card-groups .card-default>.card-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.card-groups .card-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card-groups h4.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-groups .card-title>a {
  color: #454545;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-groups .more-less {
  float: right;
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card-groups .card-default>.card-heading+.panel-collapse>.card-body {
  border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}


/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */

body {
  background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container demo">

  <div class="card-groups" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <div class="card card-default">
      <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-default">
      <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-default">
      <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #3
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel-group -->


</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 2):

replace your toggle function with this

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.card-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');

        $(e.target).prev(".card-heading").toggleClass('bg-dark');
         $(e.target).prev(".card-heading").toggleClass('text-light');
}
```

add this to your styling

```css
.card-heading.bg-dark a{
   color:#fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In here what I did was used three different functions with three different id s. And then relevant function to be called after clicked.

```js
function toggleIcon01() {
        $("#headingOne").toggleClass('bg-dark');
  $("#atext1").toggleClass('text-white');
}
function toggleIcon02() {
        $("#headingTwo").toggleClass('bg-dark');
  $("#atext2").toggleClass('text-white');
}
function toggleIcon03() {
        $("#headingThree").toggleClass('bg-dark');
  $("#atext3").toggleClass('text-white');
}
```

```css
.card-groups .card {
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .card-groups .card-default {
        border-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .card-groups .card-default > .card-heading {
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #212121;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .card-groups .card-title {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .card-groups h4.card-title {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .card-groups .card-title > a {
        color: #454545;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .card-groups .more-less {
        float: right;
        color: #454545;
      font-size:20px;
    }

    .card-groups .card-default > .card-heading + .panel-collapse > .card-body {
        border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
    background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container demo">
    
    <div class="card-groups" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne"> 
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a id="atext1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" onclick="toggleIcon01()">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="card-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a id="atext2" onclick="toggleIcon02()" class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a onclick="toggleIcon03()" id="atext3" class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <i class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- panel-group -->
    
    
</div><!-- container -->
```